# How to use instgrm.Embeds.process() in custom element?

Tags: javascript, instagram-api, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I'm trying to make a custom element that can display an instagram post. I'm trying to follow this https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/#oembed .

To embed the post I have to include a blockquote element and the instagram embed script.

```
    <script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

My problem is that I can't get this script to work.

I through looking at other posts I learned I cannot add the script with innerHTML. So I added the script with this:

```
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('async', '');
    script.src = '//www.instagram.com/embed.js';
```

and I learned that I can manually initialize this with:

```
    window.instgrm.Embeds.process();
```

so I added:

```
    script.onload = () => window.instgrm.Embeds.process();
```

I have tried appending the script in different ways like these:

```
    this.append(script);
    document.body.append(script);
    document.head.append(script);
```

None of these has worked. The blockquote displays without the image the same as it does without the script. I can see that I have successfully created and appended the script element using the browser developer tools, but I can't see that window.instgrm.Embeds.process(); is doing any thing. It doesn't show any error messages either. Am I calling this incorrectly? It works very simply if I just embed with out using a custom element but I would like to be able to add instagram posts with a single custom element.

Comment: After trying to figure this out for a while it seems to me that window.instgrm.Embeds.process() is not able to detect the blockquote element when it is inside a shadow dom. Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: I just realized, I think I should have used my custom element inside a slot element in its parent rather than directly inside. I will try it when I have a chance.

Comment: Use Instagram in light dom and slot or don't use shadow dom for your custom elememt